# JavaScript interpolation and template literals not allowing me to push to array

Tags: javascript, string, string-interpolation

I have a need for referencing an array name out of other variables values. Below is a simple program that doesn't push the value into an array. I was hoping someone could determine why. There is no runtime error but when you print the array it has not been pushed. I am creating a 4 person card game that currrently works by having a 2D array with 4 players. I want to deal the cards to P0cards P1Cards.... instead of the 2D players[[],[],[],[]] array.
My idea of using `$p{i}.push(card)` is not working

```
class Card{
    constructor(suit, value){
        this.value = value;
        this.suit = suit;
    }
}
let deck = [];
let players = [[],[],[],[]];

var p0Cards = [];
var p1Cards = [];
var p2Cards = [];
var p3Cards = [];

function deal(){
    //players 1,2,3,4
    for(let i = 0; i < 4; i++){
        //cards 1,2,3,4,5,6
        for(let j = 0; j < 6; j++){
            let card = deck.pop();
            //players[i].push(card);
            `$p{i}.push(card)`;  //this is what I would like to do.
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You can't access a variable if all you have is a `string` that is the name of the variable

Comment: are you trying to do deep copy?

Comment: String literals do not evalutate code on the fly. They create strings.

Comment: http://xyproblem.info/

Comment: Please describe why you need this, as there might be another way to approach this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you make your `arr` part of an object? Then you can access it with the use of a string.

```js
let myVars = {}
myVars.arr = []
let x = 'arr';
myVars[x].push(2);
myVars.arr.push(3);
console.log(myVars.arr);
// myVars.arr = [2, 3]
```

Comment: This is going to work thank you very much. I edited my post to clarify my question for future readers. Much appriciated.